# sql function in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scalar function for formatting the text into uppercase and remove leading, trailing spaces etc. During an insert operation in a stored procedure, I'm invoking the function like this:

```
insert into tablename(col1,col2) values ( dbo.function_name(value1),value2)
```

Here the col1 is NOT NULL. The above statement is throwing an error "Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL". But if you run the function alone, it return the value properly.

Please help explain where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If the function works properly on its own, are you sure it's not the col2/value2 causing the violation?

Comment: And, related to Joe's question, are you sure that value1 in the stored procedure is itself not null when the function is invoked?  And does the SQL statement work when run in isolation?  For example, if there is a 'col3' in the table that is both NOT NULL and has no default set, then the insert will fail.

Comment: the return type of the function is varchar(max). But the column data type is varchar(90). Is it cause a problem

Comment: if i remove that function, insertion work fine. It shows that only the function return NULL value. Also im passing the value to the function is NOT NULL. Actually im passing the values which is from another table. If it doesnot having value, then even if you remove the function it should throw the same error right

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table(Col1,Col2)
values (isnull(dbo.function_name(value1),''),value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try placing the value in a variable first and to help when you debug it.

```
DECLARE @val1 varchar(100)
SET @val1 = dbo.function_name(value1)
PRINT @val1 -- print it to see if we get what we expect.

SET @val1 = isnull(@val1,'') -- We can also check for null

insert into tablename(col1,col2) values ( @val1,value2)
```

This will at least confirm what is happening during execution and you can confirm the function is operating as you expect.

Comment: Im inserting multiple rows from selecting multiple rows from another table.so it is not possible to get the return value at the middle.

Comment: ok well in that case is it possible some of those values you are selecting from the other table are NULL and hence your function is failing?  You can handle that by using the ISNULL function.

Comment: From the comment on another answer I see you are not handling nulls in your function so what i suggested will probably fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a short but complete example that actually demonstrates the problem to your question. The following does not produce any errors, but I'm having to guess in a lot of places:

```
create table tablename (
    col1 varchar(20) not null,
    col2 varchar(10) null
)
go
create function dbo.function_name (
    @InVal varchar(20)
)
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    return UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@InVal)))
end
go
create procedure dbo.procname
    @value1 varchar(20),
    @value2 varchar(10)
as
insert into tablename(col1,col2) values ( dbo.function_name(@value1),@value2)
go
exec dbo.procname '   abc   ','def'
go
select * from tablename
```

Result:

```
col1   col2
ABC    def
```

Comment: The same way Im doing so...
<code>
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FORMAT]
(
 @i_text varchar(max)

)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
 -- Declare the return variable here
 

 -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
 RETURN UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@i_text)));

 

END
</code>